# Program demonstrate file IO operations

Tags: c, linux

Im trying to get started with io operations with c programming. i'm often facing the error 
" segmentation fault core dumped ". is there any one to clearly explain why im getting this error.
and how to avoid this silly error angain?

thanks in advance..

```
struct Subscriber { char *name; char msisdn[10+1]; };

int main() {

  FILE * ostream;
  ostream = fopen("UsersData.dat","w");
  struct Subscriber record;
  do {
    printf(" Enter subscriber record[name<Ent>msisdn<Ent>] :");
    scanf("%s",&record.name);
    scanf("%s",&record.msisdn);
    printf("Record [ %s | %s ] \n", record.name, record.msisdn);
    fwrite(&record, sizeof(record), 1, ostream);
    printf(" Do want to Insert new record? [y/n] : ");
    fflush(stdin);
  } while ('y' == getc(stdin));
  fclose(ostream);
  printf(" file closed ");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to make the code easily readable.

Comment: may I ask why did you tag it as C++ question, when this is fully pure C? Also please structure your code, it is hard to read anything at all

Comment: Why on _earth_ would you write code like this? o.O

Comment: Memory errors can be very hard to debug. Your question's too vague.

Comment: @simonzack: The problem with this code is plainly obvious.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit For his code, but not to "avoid this silly error again".

Comment: @simonzack: When he fixes this problem, he'll know how not to make it again.

Comment: Even unformatted, the char* plus no aparrent malloc was a bit of a giveaway.

Comment: Exactly. Debuggers are great fun and all but sometimes you have to resort to simply reading your code.

Comment: Not only debuggers are great tools, compilers are too. This code her e should show plenty of diagnostics. E.g the `&` operators in your `scanf` calls are plain wrong. Please put more effort in correcting your code yourself before posting, here. Voting to close.

Comment: @JensGustedt: None of this is worthy of closevoting. Downvoting perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type `Subscriber` contains a member named `name` of type `char*`; unfortunately you never allocate any memory for this pointer to point to. When you later do a `scanf`, you're trying to read into a `char` buffer that does not exist.

Why don't you make `name` an array, like `msisdn`?

Also, don't write your code in an illegible rectangular block. That's... weird.

Comment: sorry a little and thanks a lot for ur answer and suggestion Guru